# Как создать директиву в angular

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2, angular4, angular5

Читал про то как создать директиву, однако нашёл только про то как воздействовать на css,никак не пойму как применить к html. Нужно реализовать следущую задачу:

Нужно создать директиву [list], применив который к тегу div, появиться меню из переменной 
x=['html','css','js']
т.е. код должен выглядеть так:

```
x = [“HTML”, “CSS”, “JS”]

<div [list]=”x”>

</div>

в последствии внутри div получим:

<ul>

<li>HTML</li>

<li>CSS</li>

<li>JS</li>

</ul>
```

буду признателен подробным объяснениям

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-menu-directive

app.component.ts:

```
    listItems = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JS'];
```

app.component.html:

```html
<div list [listItems]="listItems"></div>
```

list.directive.ts:

```
      @Input() listItems = [];

      constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        let ul = this.renderer.createElement('ul');
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, ul);

        this.listItems.forEach(item => {
          let text = this.renderer.createText(item);
          let li = this.renderer.createElement('li');

          this.renderer.appendChild(li, text);
          this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement.children[0], li);
        })
      }
```